# CKEditor stylesSet add outline DIV

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a problem with addStyle at CKEditor

I want to addStyle a DIV box around a P-tag.

The code looks like this

```
<P> bla bli blu </ p>
```

And now I want the following.

```
<Div class="templateText"> <p> bla bli blu </ p> </ div>
```

With addStyle the following is.

```
{Name: 'TemplateText', element: 'div', attributes: {'class': 'templateText'}}
```

When I select "Template Text", the following text will appear. The P-Tag disappears. Why?

```
<Div class="templateText">bla bli blu</ div>
```